# Declare acronyms and abbreviations to automatically correct spaces after periods?

Tags: spacing, punctuation, typography

If I understand correctly, (La)TeX assumes that a period after a lower-case letter ends a sentence while a period after an upper-case letter does not.  Unfortunately, my documents usually contain plenty of acronyms and abbreviations.  Unless I remember to use `\@`, the spacing after periods is wrong:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=150},varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\makebox[0.7in][l]{Incorrect:}%
Your computer needs more RAM.  I can give you some.\\
\makebox[0.7in][l]{Correct:}%
Your computer needs more RAM\@.  I can give you some.\\
\makebox[0.7in][l]{Incorrect:}%
Colors (red, blue, etc.) are nice.\\
\makebox[0.7in][l]{Correct:}%
Colors (red, blue, etc.\@) are nice.
\end{document}
```

[image: rendering of the above document]

Is it possible to declare certain strings to be acronyms or abbreviations to invert this assumption?  If so, this would reduce the number of spacing errors in my documents.

For example:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=150},varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{magicalacronymhelper}
\declareacronym{RAM}
\declareabbr{etc}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\makebox[0.7in][l]{Correct:}%
Your computer needs more RAM.  I can give you some.\\
\makebox[0.7in][l]{Correct:}%
Your computer needs more RAM\@.  I can give you some.\\
\makebox[0.7in][l]{Correct:}%
Colors (red, blue, etc.) are nice.\\
\makebox[0.7in][l]{Correct:}%
Colors (red, blue, etc.\@) are nice.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the `ltugboat` document class has a command `\acro` that corrects for the end of a sentence.  (it does other things as well, such as stepping the type size down a point to de-emphasize the appearance of in-line uppercase -- we don't like how small caps look in this context --, but that's easily ignored.)  you're welcome to steal the idea; look for `ltugboat.cls` on ctan.  (it doesn't handle the "etc." case; you're on your own for that.)

Comment: The issue the with etc. is that it is an abbreviation and that it can legitimately occur at the end of a sentence. At this point you do not want to to quell the end of sentence spacing.

Comment: @ArTourter:  True.  In that case, I'd add an `\@` to force it to be interpreted as a sentence-ending period.  For example:  `I like citrus flavors: orange, lemon, lime, etc\@.  They are tasty.`  I rarely end sentences with an abbreviation, so inverting the default behavior of periods after abbreviations would fix more than it would break.

Comment: Simplest (and some would argue most typographically correct) solution is to use `\frenchspacing` so the issue just goes away.

Comment: @RichardHansen -- the problem with adding `\@` to "etc." is that it will in any event be interpreted as ending a sentence (since it's lowercase).  what you want to do is prevent it from indicating the end of a sentence in those (randomly occurring) cases where it doesn't.  that's where the "slash-space" is needed.  as for david's comment regarding `\frenchspacing`, there are situations where this can cause confusion; i've definitely seen them, though i can't put my hands on one right now -- that may call for rewriting rather than a spacing "fix".

Comment: @barbarabeeton: There are two ways to make the space after a period behave like a normal inter-word space:  `foo.\@ bar` or `foo.\ bar`.  I was hoping there was a way to automatically add `\@` after declared acronyms (like `RAM`) and abbreviations (like `etc.`) but with a way to manually cancel it when I want the normal TeX behavior (e.g., when an acronym ends a sentence).  From egreg's response, it doesn't sound like this is possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to do this automatically, unless you're willing to use XeLaTeX and the unsupported package `xesearch`.

The best thing you can do is to define macros `\acro` and `\abbr`:

```
\newcommand{\acro}[1]{#1\@}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\abbr}{\@ifstar\@firstofone\@abbr}
\newcommand{\@abbr}[1]{#1.\@}
\makeatother
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\acro}[1]{#1\@}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\abbr}{\@ifstar\@firstofone\@abbr}
\newcommand{\@abbr}[1]{#1.\@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
Your computer needs more \acro{RAM}.  I can give you some.\\
Your computer needs more RAM\@.  I can give you some.\\[3pt]
Colors (red, blue, \abbr{etc}) are nice.\\
Colors (red, blue, etc.\@) are nice.\\[3pt]
I like citrus flavors: orange, lemon, lime, \abbr*{etc}. They are tasty\\
I like citrus flavors: orange, lemon, lime, etc\@. They are tasty
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't `\newcommand{\@abbr}[1]{#1\@.}` be `\newcommand{\@abbr}[1]{#1.\@}`?

Comment: @RichardHansen Yes, it should. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks! Too bad it can't be automatically done.  I'm just as likely to remember to type `\abbr{}` or `\acro{}` as I am to type `\@`.  :)

Comment: What's the purpose of all the `\@ifstar\@firstofone` business? And why do you suggest in the case of `\abbr` but not `\acro`?

Comment: @Cerran `\abbr` is supposed to act on lowercase letters, while `\acro` on uppercase ones, and they require different treatment; `\abbr*` is for when punctuation follows.

Comment: I couldn't quite figure out what `\@firstofone` does. And it looks like there is a definition of `\abbr*` but not `\abbr` because there's no "else", which I guess means I don't understand `\@ifstar`, either.

Comment: @Cerran `\@firstofone` just strips the braces off the argument if there's a `*`; if there's no `*`, `\@abbr` is executed on the given argument.